# iOS: Search for video files in cashes folder and each subfolder

Tags: ios, search, directory, subdirectory

Is there a possibility to search for all files of a certain kind (e.g. mp4) in a folder and all of its subfolders? By now I'm able to this for one folder at a time using this code:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:cachesPath error:nil];
NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.mp4'"];
NSArray *filesWithAttr = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];

NSLog(@"%@", filesWithAttr);
```

But I have a lot of subfolders in my cashes folder. Do I have to through each and every one of them and check for mp4-files or is there any simpler solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at `[fm fileExistsAtPath:yourPath isDirectory:&foo];` and `[fm subpathsAtPath:yourPath];`

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this easily with getting all subpaths and then filtering them. So replace your `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` with `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath` and it should work. The function does a **deep enumeration**, so all subdirectories are also included.

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *dirContents = [fm subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:cachesPath error:nil];
NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.mp4'"];
NSArray *filesWithAttr = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
```

Function description:
[Apple iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath%3aerror%3a)